# doxygen class and function variables not getting documented properly

Tags: c++, documentation, doxygen

I am using `Doxygen` for the first time.I am trying to document my c++ project using `Doxygen`.
I am not getting proper documentation for my class/variables.
Here is the code:

```
/**
 * Parse tree node for each symbol
 */
class node
{
    public:

node* left;/**left-address of left child*/
node* right;/**right-address of right child*/   
char ch;/**ch-character in the node*/


/**
 *constructor for node
 *
 *@param le left child address
 *@param ri right child address
 *@param c character to be put in the node
 */
node(node* le,node* ri,char c)
{
    left=le;
    right=ri;
    ch=c;
}

};
```

and also here:

```
/**
 *@brief returns priority
 *
 *Takes an operand and returns its priotity based on precedence.
 *Return -1 for '(' so that it always remains on the stack until ')' is encountered in infix.
 *
 *@param c operand or '('
 *
 *@return priority value
 */ 

int priority(char c)          
{ 
     switch(c)
    { 
        case '>': return  0 ; 
        case 'V': return  1 ; 
        case '^': return  1 ; 
        case '~': return  2 ; 
        case '(': return -1 ;           
        } 
    }

    stack <char> op ;//*<stack of operaators*/
```

Neither do i get any documentation in snippet1 for my member variables and class.Same for `priority` function and `op` global variable.
I have tried both notations for my variables:
`stack <char> op ;//*<stack of operaators*/`
and
`node* left;/**left-address of left child*/`

All it showed was that the `op` variable existed,and priority function existed under the documentation without any of the description given in the comments.Same is the case for class `node`.Can someone help me see what's wrong with this?

Comment: The type of comment that you used for the member variables is for before-item documentation, but you added it after the item. Use `//!<` for after-item documentation, or move your comment before the variables.

Comment: Like Rene write use in both cases `///<` comment or `/**<` the form used for op: `//*<` is also wrong. See also the section about documenting the code in the manual (http://www.doxygen.org/manual/docblocks.html)

Comment: Is the `priority` function in another file? Try `/** \file */` at the top of the file.

Comment: Thanks guys .Made the changes according to after-item documentation,and also adding `@file` helped,it was in a different file.